# display multiple models in one view and get slug url for each post - django

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

i am trying to show data from multiple models in one single view and one single template and i succeed with that but i have problem , the problem is posts from `android` model keep show at first because i have added `android` first in html page but what i want to do is show posts by date published what should i do

models.py :

```
class android(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,default="")
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250,default="")
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)

    def get_image(self):
        if self.app_image and hasattr(self.app_image, 'url'):
            return self.app_image.url
        else:
            return '/path/to/default/image'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
        
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-post_date',)


class PCgames(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,default="")
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250,default="")
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)

    def get_image(self):
        if self.app_image and hasattr(self.app_image, 'url'):
            return self.app_image.url
        else:
            return '/path/to/default/image'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
        
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-post_date',)
```

views.py :

```
def home_page(request):
    pcgamesforhome = PCgames.objects.all()
    androidforhome = Android.objects.all()
    context = {'pcgamesforhome' : pcgamesforhome,'androidforhome' : androidforhome}
    return render(request,'html_file/home.html',context=context)
```

home.html :

```
 <div class="container">
     <div class='row'>


{% for android in androidforhome %}

      <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 website-thumb'>
                    
         <a href="{{ android.slug }}">
                  
         <img src="{{ android.get_image }}" class='image_control_for_home_page_pc_games' alt=''> </a>
                    
         <h3><a href="{{ home_page.slug }}" class="font_control_for_home_page_pc_games_name">{{ android.name }}</a></h3> </div>
{% endfor %}
  </div>

        <div class="container">
            <div class='row'>


{% for home_page in pcgamesforhome %}

      <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 website-thumb'>
                    
           <a href="{{ home_page.slug }}">
                  
           <img src="{{ home_page.get_image }}" class='image_control_for_home_page_pc_games' alt=''> </a>
                    
           <h3><a href="{{ home_page.slug }}" class="font_control_for_home_page_pc_games_name">{{ home_page.name }}</a></h3> </div>
{% endfor %}
  </div>
```

so now what should i do to show posts from all models order by date ?

Comment: why not create a model category  with foreign key to post model instead of having two separate models ?   Slug as a field  is supposed to be unique not null

Comment: can you give me example

Answer (score 0):

your database structure is wrong. instead of having two model for android and PC, you can have one model and a field specifying object type with choices

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    Type = (
        ('android', 'android'),
        ('pc', 'pc'),
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,default="")
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250,default="")
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=Type)
```

if you like to have a special field for each android or pc, you can create fields with blank and null true attr.

views.py:

```
# get all of them and order them by creation date
Foo.obejcts.all().order_by('-post_date')

# get android type objects
Foo.objects.filter(type='android')

# get pc type objects
Foo.objects.filter(type='pc')
```

Comment: and how to pass data to view then template ?

Answer (score 0):

a basic example would be

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
       return self.name

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField(blank=True)
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
       return self.title

    class Meta:
        #recent post in top 
        ordering = ['-post_date']
```

in views  to filter based on category:

```
pc_games = Post.objects.select_related("category_set").filter(category__name='pc_games')
 android = Post.objects.select_related("category_set").filter(category__name='android')
```